# Is there 'USE DATASET' in bigquery?

Tags: database, google-bigquery

Is there 'USE DATASET' in GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM Bigquery like we have in hive?
`USE DATABASE NAME`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you share your use case?